# Optimizing DB Model : N2N relationship postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql, data-modeling

I have a very simple model. A table Articles has 10 relations : 2 are 12N, 8 are N2N.
The issue is that this table can contain 10K rows on average, and some of the N2N relation tables have more than 200 records.

All in all, querying the data from table Articles with all join records leads to a total of 10 849 200 000 000 records, that is obviously too much.

therefore I have to change the model to optimize it, maybe avoiding N2N relations but including some of the N2N data as JSONB column in Articles, but this may lead into complexity while updating/adding/deleting records in the N2N tables

What would be a better approach in your opinion ?
What is the best way to update/delete/add records in JSONB columns ?

running postgres 12 in GCloud

Thks

**[EDIT]**

here is the article table (on a `data` schema)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.articles
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    title character varying(3000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    "prioriteId" uuid,
    "isAlerte" boolean DEFAULT false,
    "categorieId" uuid,
    "publicationStartDate" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT '2021-12-03 14:20:03.172'::timestamp without time zone,
    "publicationEndDate" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT '2021-12-03 14:20:03.172'::timestamp without time zone,
    "hasAction" boolean DEFAULT false,
    "briefDescription" character varying(3000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    content text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT ''::text,
    contact1 character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    contact2 character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    author character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT ''::character varying,
    "recordCreationDate" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "recordUpdateDate" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT "PK_0a6e2c450d83e0b6052c2793334" PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_278d87b271a80d56e5d6cc0f888" FOREIGN KEY ("categorieId")
        REFERENCES data.ref_categories (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_a55acd217d26e0d60f57b5f38f7" FOREIGN KEY ("prioriteId")
        REFERENCES data.ref_priorites (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE data.articles
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: IDX_0a6e2c450d83e0b6052c279333

-- DROP INDEX data."IDX_0a6e2c450d83e0b6052c279333";

CREATE INDEX "IDX_0a6e2c450d83e0b6052c279333"
    ON data.articles USING btree
    (id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

here is one of the 10 reference tables. All 10 tables have similar definition

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.ref_metiers
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    section character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    key character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    value character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    parent character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "order" integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_24035e57be39b22b5ee482f4a72" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE data.ref_metiers
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: IDX_24035e57be39b22b5ee482f4a7

-- DROP INDEX data."IDX_24035e57be39b22b5ee482f4a7";

CREATE INDEX "IDX_24035e57be39b22b5ee482f4a7"
    ON data.ref_metiers USING btree
    (id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Here is one of the 8 tables to create the N2N relation

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.articles_metiers
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "articleId" uuid NOT NULL,
    "metierId" uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_62b37716d5cae9a5a9bee96c4da" PRIMARY KEY (id, "articleId", "metierId"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_43128a90c1671f1639d23ea3d5e" FOREIGN KEY ("articleId")
        REFERENCES data.articles (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_f42358a7091bc79819c714987e4" FOREIGN KEY ("metierId")
        REFERENCES data.ref_metiers (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

the query (very simple)

```
select 
    a.*,
    m.id,
    d.*,
    ad.*,
    f.key,
    f.value,
    me.key,
    me.value,
    pe.key,
    pe.value,
    po.key,
    po.value,
    ser.key,
    ser.value,
    con.key,
    con.value
from data.articles a
    
inner join data.articles_magasins am
on a."id" = am."articleId"
inner join data.hypermarches_stores m
on am."magasinId" = m."id"

inner join data.articles_documents ad
on a."id" = ad."articleId"
inner join data.base_documents d
on ad."documentId" = d."id"

inner join data.articles_fonctions af
on a."id" = af."articleId"
inner join data.ref_fonctions f
on af."fonctionId" = f."id"

inner join data.articles_metiers ame
on a."id" = ame."articleId"
inner join data.ref_metiers me
on ame."metierId" = me."id"

inner join data.articles_perimetres ape
on a."id" = ape."articleId"
inner join data.ref_perimetres pe
on ape."perimetreId" = pe."id"
    
inner join data.articles_poles apo
on a."id" = apo."articleId"
inner join data.ref_poles po
on apo."poleId" = po."id"
    
inner join data.articles_services ase
on a."id" = ase."articleId"
inner join data.ref_services ser
on ase."serviceId" = ser."id"
    
inner join data.articles_statuts_contribution acon
on a."id" = acon."articleId"
inner join data.ref_statuts_contrib con
on acon."statutId" = con."id"
```

and a screenshot of the plan in PDAdmin (not sure what info is relevant)
[image]

**[EDIT 2]**
adding a `where a.id="lklmklmkm"` condition too get back only 1 article takes 7s (the dev server is very small to be honest but it shhould be faster anyway)

its explain analyze :

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=2066.53..27008.53 rows=394240 width=6493) (actual time=92.243..341.860 rows=394240 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..259.68 rows=1 width=1048) (actual time=0.564..1.101 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (acon.""statutId"" = con.id)"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 5"
"        ->  Seq Scan on articles_statuts_contribution acon  (cost=0.00..249.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.554..1.089 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              Filter: (""articleId"" = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 9999"
"        ->  Seq Scan on ref_statuts_contrib con  (cost=0.00..10.30 rows=30 width=1048) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=6 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2066.53..22806.46 rows=394240 width=5461) (actual time=91.676..247.043 rows=394240 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=2066.53..14342.47 rows=7040 width=2365) (actual time=77.916..87.851 rows=7040 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (ame.""metierId"" = me.id)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2055.86..14310.70 rows=7040 width=1349) (actual time=77.880..84.789 rows=7040 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1000.57..7340.93 rows=176 width=1333) (actual time=36.323..40.931 rows=176 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Gather  (cost=1000.28..5352.65 rows=22 width=164) (actual time=30.476..30.682 rows=22 loops=1)"
"                                Workers Planned: 2"
"                                Workers Launched: 2"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..4350.45 rows=9 width=164) (actual time=17.455..20.764 rows=7 loops=3)"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on articles_documents ad  (cost=0.00..4288.83 rows=9 width=81) (actual time=17.434..20.702 rows=7 loops=3)"
"                                            Filter: (""articleId"" = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 73326"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using ""IDX_87eab207e6374a967ae94feb8e"" on base_documents d  (cost=0.28..6.85 rows=1 width=83) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=22)"
"                                            Index Cond: (id = ad.""documentId"")"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..1986.11 rows=8 width=1169) (actual time=0.266..0.451 rows=8 loops=22)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..1986.07 rows=8 width=1169) (actual time=5.830..9.852 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..237.99 rows=1 width=1153) (actual time=0.767..1.265 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                            Join Filter: (af.""fonctionId"" = f.id)"
"                                            Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..227.31 rows=1 width=137) (actual time=0.755..1.251 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using ""IDX_0a6e2c450d83e0b6052c279333"" on articles a  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=121) (actual time=0.021..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (id = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on articles_fonctions af  (cost=0.00..219.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.730..1.217 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                        Filter: (""articleId"" = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 9999"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on ref_fonctions f  (cost=0.00..10.30 rows=30 width=1048) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on articles_metiers ame  (cost=0.00..1748.00 rows=8 width=32) (actual time=5.057..8.576 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                            Filter: (""articleId"" = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 79992"
"                    ->  Materialize  (cost=1055.29..6881.87 rows=40 width=32) (actual time=0.236..0.239 rows=40 loops=176)"
"                          ->  Gather  (cost=1055.29..6881.67 rows=40 width=32) (actual time=41.545..41.620 rows=40 loops=1)"
"                                Workers Planned: 2"
"                                Workers Launched: 2"
"                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=55.29..5877.67 rows=17 width=32) (actual time=29.068..35.769 rows=13 loops=3)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (am.""magasinId"" = m.id)"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on articles_magasins am  (cost=0.00..5822.33 rows=17 width=32) (actual time=28.870..35.563 rows=13 loops=3)"
"                                            Filter: (""articleId"" = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 133320"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=52.35..52.35 rows=235 width=16) (actual time=0.302..0.303 rows=235 loops=1)"
"                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 20kB"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on hypermarches_stores m  (cost=0.00..52.35 rows=235 width=16) (actual time=0.062..0.214 rows=235 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=10.30..10.30 rows=30 width=1048) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=41 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on ref_metiers me  (cost=0.00..10.30 rows=30 width=1048) (actual time=0.007..0.013 rows=41 loops=1)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3536.13 rows=56 width=3144) (actual time=0.002..0.006 rows=56 loops=7040)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3535.85 rows=56 width=3144) (actual time=13.749..17.341 rows=56 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1761.92 rows=8 width=1048) (actual time=5.872..9.430 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                          Join Filter: (ape.""perimetreId"" = pe.id)"
"                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 56"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on ref_perimetres pe  (cost=0.00..10.30 rows=30 width=1048) (actual time=0.018..0.020 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1748.04 rows=8 width=32) (actual time=0.731..1.174 rows=8 loops=8)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on articles_perimetres ape  (cost=0.00..1748.00 rows=8 width=32) (actual time=5.844..9.379 rows=8 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (""articleId"" = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 79992"
"                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1773.25 rows=7 width=2096) (actual time=0.984..0.987 rows=7 loops=8)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1773.21 rows=7 width=2096) (actual time=7.866..7.880 rows=7 loops=1)"
"                                Join Filter: (ase.""serviceId"" = ser.id)"
"                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 77"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on ref_services ser  (cost=0.00..10.30 rows=30 width=1048) (actual time=0.009..0.011 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1759.78 rows=7 width=1080) (actual time=0.350..0.654 rows=7 loops=12)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1759.74 rows=7 width=1080) (actual time=4.190..7.830 rows=7 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..229.68 rows=1 width=1048) (actual time=0.551..1.048 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                  Join Filter: (apo.""poleId"" = po.id)"
"                                                  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on articles_poles apo  (cost=0.00..219.00 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.543..1.038 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                        Filter: (""articleId"" = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 9999"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on ref_poles po  (cost=0.00..10.30 rows=30 width=1048) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on articles_services ase  (cost=0.00..1530.00 rows=7 width=32) (actual time=3.637..6.776 rows=7 loops=1)"
"                                                  Filter: (""articleId"" = '000b827c-7a6a-4430-a28d-827c286983a5'::uuid)"
"                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 69993"
"Planning Time: 2.550 ms"
"Execution Time: 362.384 ms"
```

[update 3]
Have applied some configs suggested by @sticky bit :

- remove the unnecessary `id` column to the N2N tables
- add some indexes on the N2N Tables (`articleId` and `metierId`) in the previous example
- apply `ANALYZE` to update the statistics

Still no luck

Have then tried to find which join has an issue.
I found this one that takes 3s to retrieve 400K rows (again the dev server is very small, but both CPU and Memory are not full at all, this is a managed postgres on GCP ):

```
select 
    a.*,
    m.id
from data.articles a
inner join data.articles_magasins am
on a."id" = am."articleId"
inner join data.hypermarches_stores m
on am."magasinId" = m."id"
```

- `articles_magasins` has 400 000 rows
- `data.articles` has 10 000 rows
- `data.hypermarches_stores` has 235 rows
- `articles_magasins` has an index on `articleId` and another index on `magasinId`
- both `data.articles` and `data.hypermarches_stores` have indexes on `id`

However the execution plan doesn't use any of the indexes

```
"Hash Join  (cost=473.29..9534.67 rows=400000 width=137)"
"  Hash Cond: (am.""magasinId"" = m.id)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=418.00..8410.44 rows=400000 width=137)"
"        Hash Cond: (am.""articleId"" = a.id)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on articles_magasins am  (cost=0.00..6942.00 rows=400000 width=32)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=293.00..293.00 rows=10000 width=121)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on articles a  (cost=0.00..293.00 rows=10000 width=121)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=52.35..52.35 rows=235 width=16)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on hypermarches_stores m  (cost=0.00..52.35 rows=235 width=16)"
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: If the schema is fixed, don't use JSON. (Continue to) use relational means, that's what RDBMS are built for and what they handle the best.

Comment: understand. My strategy might be to keep the RDBMS schema as a "core", but to defined a kind of exposed schema with JSON columns to prepare data to be sent to the front end, thus avoiding some perfs issues when querying the model from the client. Main disadvantage is to manage upgrade of the exposed schema any time the core one is upgraded.

Comment: Denormalization is the last resort to solve performance issues and needs great care, again I advise not to do it. Have you already tried analyzing your queries and put appropriate indexes on the tables yet? Again, RDBMS are meant to handle relations and offer the right tools for that task on board. Do you even have a performance problem or is this a case of premature optimization?

Comment: the main issue is the volumetry. Look at the number of total records. I'm working around by applying pagination but this is a bad workaround in my opinion.
However, the execution plan is weird in PGDAMIN. The join are only on foreignKey, which means the execution should use the primary key indexes created on primary keys (that are UUIDs).. But reading at the execution plan,  I'm not sure it is using these indexes

Comment: If you got an actual issue with a query, you might want to ask a question including the objects' (tables' and indexes') `CREATE` statements the `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` and the query of course.

Comment: Does the front end need to retrieve all the 10 849 200 000 000 records at the same time, or does the query triggered by the front end filter dramatically the number of rows in the result ?

Comment: @Sticky bit  : Will enhance my question with the create, the query (I'm using an ORM but will catch the SQL statments.)

Comment: @Edouard : of course not, but the idea is to fullfill the cache in a Redis cluster in order to speed up the query time from the FE. In a subset of 1000 Articles, the query are 10 times faster.

Comment: So you could fulfill the cache with a background process, step by step, or trigger the cache update when a table is modified, or fulfill the cache with partial joins ... I agree with @sticky bit : denormalize the data model is risky and would not improve the performance especially in case of many-to-many relationships.

Comment: And by the way, do yourself a favor and don't use double quoted, case sensitive identifiers. They only make things complicated and the identifiers in the database don't need to be "pretty". "Pretty" headers are a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: `articles_metiers` (and the analog) has no index on `("articleId", "metierId")`? Why? The index created by the primary key is useless here as it is "poisoned" by the (probably even unnecessary) `id` column as it's first indexed column. And maybe it would be worth to try hash indexes instead of B-tree indexes on all the single `id`s. Hash indexes support `=` operations better than B-trees.

Comment: will apply your suggestions on indexes and get back to you. Agree with "pretty" column names (camel case in this situation). the point is that the db is created and managed via TypeOrm and I'm lazy in rewriting the column names as TypeOrm is using the typescript definition.

Comment: FYI, I fixed the issue by creating some materialized views that are refreshed when the M2M tables are updated (any CRUD operations on these tables). Adding the CONCURRENTLY clause ensure that the views are still available even when the refresh is on going. Have tests by applying 10 CRUD operations per seconds, and the data are always updated and never locked.

This has also the benefit to prepare the data for the front end on several axis and keys depending on the business requirement;